# Combining sum statements to one table

Tags: sql-server-2008

The first part of the code creates a table based on SUM statements:

```
SELECT varday, COUNT(*) AS Vol,
SUM(FOPS_REHAB) AS FOPS_REHAB,
SUM(FOPS_RECOVERY) AS FOPS_RECOVERY
  FROM table
  WHERE PROCESSING_DATE > '31/aug/2012' and rownumber =1 
GROUP BY varday
ORDER BY varday
```

However, I have two other code parts that I want to combine into the code above but they have an extra 'where' criteria.

So these are the two sum statements I want to combine to the table above;

```
select SUM(Current_Balance_Amount)as rec_bal, varday
 into #temp
  from table
   where fops_recovery = 1 and  PROCESSING_DATE > '31/aug/2012' and rownumber =1 
group by varday
ORDER BY varday


select SUM(Current_Balance_Amount)as reh_bal, varday
 into #temp
  from table
   where fops_rehab = 1 and  PROCESSING_DATE > '31/aug/2012' and rownumber =1 
group by varday
ORDER BY varday
```

So `reh_bal` and `rec_bal` are in one table with the first table which contains `FOPS_REHAB` and `FOPS_RECOVERY`. I'm having problems because they have an extra clause (`where fops recovery = 1 or fops rehab = 1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all 3 queries can be combined into one, try this:

```
select  varday, 
        COUNT(*) AS Vol,
        SUM(FOPS_REHAB) AS FOPS_REHAB,
        SUM(FOPS_RECOVERY) AS FOPS_RECOVERY,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fops_recovery = 1 THEN Current_Balance_Amount ELSE 0 END) rec_bal,
        SUM(CASE WHEN fops_rehab = 0 THEN Current_Balance_Amount ELSE 0 END) reh_bal
where   PROCESSING_DATE > '31/aug/2012' and rownumber =1 
group   by varday
ORDER   BY varday
```